# How to select random .wav/.mp3 file from folder with Garry's mod?

Tags: audio, lua, garrys-mod

I've recently started Coding a program that will replace sound effects from a default directory, in the *Source-Engine Game*, Garry's Mod.

This is the current code:

```
function GM:PlayerFootstep( ply, pos, foot, sound, volume, rf ) 
     ply:EmitSound("gear1")
     return true 
 end
```

I want to emit multiple `.wav` Sound effects, without them overlapping, and being selected at random.

I have not found any Source helpful enough on the Internet to assist, so i resorted to Stack Overflow.
I would appreciate assistance with the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to look at the [file.Find](http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/file/Find) function for this.

I'd recommend having a custom folder such as `sound/customsteps/` where you can put all your custom sounds. I would also recommend using the `.wav` format for the sound files, but some others do work (`.mp3` and `.ogg` if I recall correctly).

In your code, simply call `local snds=file.Find( "sound/customsteps/*", "GAME" )` which gives you a table, then you can simply choose a random one from the list using `local snd=snds[math.random(1,#snds)]` and play it as you do in your above code - `ply:EmitSound(snd)`.

Make sure you create the table of sounds outside of the `GM:PlayerFootstep` function, so that it only runs once. I would also recommend precaching all the sounds. You can do this by looping through the table and calling `util.PrecacheSound(path)` on them, like so:

```
for k,v in pairs(snds) do
    util.PrecacheSound(v)
end
```

So, with all that in mind - your final code should look something like this:

```
local snds=file.Find( "sound/customsteps/*", "GAME" )
for k,v in pairs(snds) do
    util.PrecacheSound(v)
end

function GM:PlayerFootstep( ply, pos, foot, sound, volume, rf ) 
    ply:EmitSound(snds[math.random(1,#snds)])
    return true
end
```

Source: [personal experience](https://github.com/MattJeanes/Base-Core/blob/master/lua/entities/base_core3/shared.lua)